# How to create dynamic jPlayer?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Below are the code of jPlayer with jQuery. I have to create jPlayer dynamic.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_0").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                webmv: "http://....",
                poster: "http://...."
            });
        },
        play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        repeat: function(event) { // Override the default jPlayer repeat event handler
            if(event.jPlayer.options.loop) {
                $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerRepeat", function() {
                    $(this).jPlayer("play");
                });
            } else {
                $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerNext", function() {
                    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 0);
                });
            }
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "webmv",
        size: {
            width: "640px",
            height: "360px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        },      
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_0"
    });
```

I have 20 jPlayers on page load. so i don't want to write this 20 times.

```
for(var i=1;i<=20;i++){

       $("#jquery_jplayer_"+i).jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    webmv: "http://..",
                    poster: "http://.."
                });
            },
            play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
                $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            },
            repeat: function(event) { // Override the default jPlayer repeat event handler
                if(event.jPlayer.options.loop) {
                    $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                    $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerRepeat", function() {
                        $(this).jPlayer("play");
                    });
                } else {
                    $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                    $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerNext", function() {
                        $("#jquery_jplayer_"+(i-1)).jPlayer("play", 0);
                    });
                }
            },
            swfPath: "jplayer/js",
            supplied: "webmv",
            size: {
                width: "640px",
                height: "360px",
                cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
            },      
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_"+i
        });
    }
```

I want to apply above code. But it didn't work for me. May be it don't create dynamic objects. Used eval() but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might give you some direction in where to start:

**JS**

Try this: create a javascript file that creates a jplayer as follows. I am defining the html with this.html = Ext.String.format(YourHtmlCodeForJplayer);

At the end you can call the jquery to instantiate it, for which im using: on(afterrender, function(){YourJqueryCodeHereThatCallsTheJplayerLibrary})

Dont forget to use unique ID's for each player. (I have a Component, Container and Interface ID) There are also problems with the audiofiles not playing, but that might just be the resourceservice im using. With normal mp4 files there isnt much of a problem.

It might also be smart to try and use the jplayer CSSSelector and CSSSelectorAncestor options when instantiating the jquery. These options allow you to change the predefined css classes/selectors/whateveryou call it.

**C#**

If you want to use C# to do this, do exactly the same. The only thing different is rendering the HTML with a HTMLgenericcontrol instead of javascript. At the end of your htmlgenericcontrol you can add a call to a javascript file that in turn uses the jquery to instantiate the players. Please note that your unique ID's will have to be created inside of C# and passed with the javascript call to your jquery instantiating method.

Please note that your server/download method needs to support range requests. Otherwise there might be problems with playing the files.

~

I understand this might be a bit confusing, but im currently working inside certain frameworks and structures, and cant really give out code, that would only confuse things more. So i hope this is usefull to you anyway!

Feel free to ask any further questions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. [Check this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jplayer/iKpGhDfDSM4) and, [this one as well](http://onyxmueller.net/testing/jplayer/). You're going to want to comment out the "ready" event from your code, and do that logic elsewhere. So, in your code:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_"+i).jPlayer({
        play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        repeat: function(event) { // Override the default jPlayer repeat event handler
            if(event.jPlayer.options.loop) {
                $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerRepeat", function() {
                    $(this).jPlayer("play");
                });
            } else {
                $(this).unbind(".jPlayerRepeat").unbind(".jPlayerNext");
                $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jPlayer.jPlayerNext", function() {
                    $("#jquery_jplayer_"+(i-1)).jPlayer("play", 0);
                });
            }
        },
        swfPath: "jplayer/js",
        supplied: "webmv",
        size: {
            width: "640px",
            height: "360px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        },      
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_"+i
    });
```

And perform the "setMedia" event in a separate function, which you will want to call from elsewhere. For example, here:

```
<ul class="jp-controls">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1" onclick="playMedia(@itemCount)">play</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

Where itemCount is the determined in the loop that dynamically generates your markup. And then have a function such as this:

```
function playMedia(itemDivId) {
    var podcastPaths = [@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", itemPodcastPaths.Select(s => "'" + s.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "'")))];
    var url = getUrl(podcastPaths[itemDivId]);

    var stream = {
        mp3: url
    };
    var selector = "#jquery_jplayer_" + itemDivId;
    $(selector).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same enviroment, 5 jplayers in the same page initializeds in a for( ){}
You need to instantiate a diferent copy of 'i' for each one.
This is done like this

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

  (function(i){

   $("#jquery_jplayer_"+i).jPlayer({
     ready: function(event){
       $(this).jPlayer("setMedia",myMediaArray);
     },
     error: function (event) {
      console.log(event.jPlayer.error);
     },
     swfPath: "../jquery.jplayer.swf",
     cssSelectorAncestor: '#flash-'+i,
     cssSelector:{
     play: '.icon-play1',
     pause: '.icon-pause1',
     seekBar: '.jp-seek-bar',
     playBar: '.ui-slider-range',
     currentTime: '.jp-current-time',
     duration: '.jp-duration'
     },
     supplied: "mp3",
     solution_play: "flash, html",
     wmode: "window",
     mobile:true,
     preload: "metadata",
     volume: 1,
     duration:true,
     smoothPlayBar: true,
     keyEnabled: true,
     errorAlerts: true
   });

  })(i);

}
```

if you don´t use

```
(function(i){
//
})(i);
```

you will end up with all players initialized as the las one.